# Ruby on rails 3.0 NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an error in my app. I have a nested from, which is rendering perfectly in the new, but not in the page where I want to see the content of all users.
This is the error:

```
NoMethodError in Resumes#index

Showing /Users/antonella/Desktop/resumin/resume/app/views/resumes/index.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `educations' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #10):

7:          <%= resume.personal_detail.address %>
8:          <%= resume.personal_detail.telephone %>
9:      </li>
10:         <% @resume.educations.each do |education| %>
11:         <li>
12:             <%= resume.education.school_name %>
13:             <%= resume.education.city %>

Rails.root: /Users/antonella/Desktop/resumin/resume
```

### resume.rb

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :personal_detail
    has_many :educations, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_detail
    attr_accessible :personal_detail_attributes 
    validates_associated :personal_detail 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:education].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
    attr_accessible :education_attributes
    validates_associated :education
end
```

### resumes_controller.rb

```
def index 
    @resumes = Resume.all
  end
```

### education.rb

```
class Education &lsaquo; ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :resume
    attr_accessible :school_name, :degree, :dates_attended, :type_of_study, :field_of_study, :city, :country
end
```

### index.html

```
<h1>All resumes</h1>
<ul>
    <% @resumes.each do |resume| %>
        <li>
            <%= resume.personal_detail.firstname %>
            <%= resume.personal_detail.lastname %>
            <%= resume.personal_detail.address %>
            <%= resume.personal_detail.telephone %>
        </li>
        <% @resume.educations.each do |education| %>
        <li>
            <%= resume.education.school_name %>
            <%= resume.education.city %>
            <%= resume.education.country %>
            <%= resume.education.dates_attended %>
            <%= resume.education.degree %>
            <%= resume.education.type_of_study %>
            <%= resume.education.field_of_study %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<% @resume.educations.each do |education| %>
```

it should be:

```
<% resume.educations.each do |education| %>
```

Note that the variable `@resume` does not exist. You only have `@resumes` and inside the loop you have `resume`.

You also have to change this part:

```
<li>
  <%= resume.education.school_name %>
  <%= resume.education.city %>
  <%= resume.education.country %>
  <%= resume.education.dates_attended %>
  <%= resume.education.degree %>
  <%= resume.education.type_of_study %>
  <%= resume.education.field_of_study %>
</li>
```

To:

```
<li>
  <%= education.school_name %>
  <%= education.city %>
  <%= education.country %>
  <%= education.dates_attended %>
  <%= education.degree %>
  <%= education.type_of_study %>
  <%= education.field_of_study %>
</li>
```